# ¿Cómo mapear correctamente la relacion de las tablas Oracle en SpringBoot?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Tengo las siguientes tablas en Oracle  y su relacion entre ellas por las FK como se observa en el diagrama
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi estan llenas en la BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas tablas yo las muestro en una pantalla con Angular y lo que se hacen sobre cada una de las tablas es realizar updates y deletes.  En la tabla principal **PRODUCTO** se puede modificar la descripcion o cambiar los subproductos o los tipos de productos , en las tablas hijas **TIPO PRODUCTO** Y **SUBPRODUCTO** se puede modificar la descripcion de cada una de ellas, aqui el detalle es que debo de agregar la validacion de que si quiero **eliminar** un registro de las tablas hijas y ese id del registro que quiero eliminar se ocupa en la tabla **PRODUCTO**, me mande un mensaje que diga que no se puede, porque ese id lo estan ocupando en otro catalogo

actualmente tengo asi mis tablas mapeadas y funciona bien para que muestre los datos y se pueda realizar los updates, deletes e insert , y te deja hacer el delete de las tablas hijas sin tema, pero pues esta mal, deberia de existir esa restriccion y lo que quiero hacer entonces es mapear correctamente las entidades para que al momento de querer eliminar no me deje hacerlo

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "PRODUCTO")
public class ProductoEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CVE_PRODUCTO")
    private String cveProducto;
    
    @Column(name = "ID_SUBPRODUCTO")
    private Integer  idSubproducto; 
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private  String descripcion; 
    
    @Column(name = "ESVALIDO")
    private String esValido;
    
    @Column(name = "ID_TIPO_PRODUCTO")
    private Integer  idTipoProducto; 
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name= "SUBPRODUCTO")
public class SubProductoEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_SUBPRODUCTO")
    private Integer  idSubproducto; 
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private  String descripcion; 
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name= "TIPO_PRODUCTO")
public class TipoProductoEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_TIPO_PRODUCTO")
    private Integer  idTipoProducto; 
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private  String descripcion; 
    
}
```

cual es la forma correcta de mapear las entidades de acuerdo al diagrama que se tiene?
he visto @OneToOne o @OneToMany pero no se en que tabla deban de ir, alguien podria ayudarme por favor